# Javac.exeはコード2を伴って終了しました が出てビルドができない

Tags: java, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2015(VS) + Xamarin で Android開発をしようと"Hello world"アプリを作成したのですが、ビルドをする際、タイトルの「Javac.exeはコード2を伴って終了しました」というエラーが出てビルドができません。

多少調べてみた結果、Javaのパスにスペースが入っているのが原因という情報があったので、一度Javaをアンインストール、C:\program files (x86)\Java\jdk から C:\Java\jdk にインストール先を移動し、環境変数を変更し、VSのXamarinのJDKのパスを通しましたが、改善しませんでした。

このエラーの改善方法があれば教えていただきたいです。

以下スペック等です。
OS:Windows10 Home(64bit)
VS 2015
JRE:ver1.8.0_231 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode, sharing)
JDK:javac 13.0.1

よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: こんな記事があるようですが。[java.exeはコード２を伴って終了しました : Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2080, 3) : error MSB6006 | Xamarin.Forms](https://itblogdsi.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-208.html)

Comment: JDK(javac)のバーションが 13.0.1 なのに JRE(runtime)のバージョンが 1.8.0 になっているという事は Java SE 8(JDK 8 + JRE 8)が別のパスにインストールされているのでしょうか？

Comment: 関連記事として、[Microsoft's Mobile OpenJDK Distribution - Xamarin](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/openjdk) によれば、Beginning with Visual Studio 15.9 and Visual Studio for Mac 7.7, Visual Studio Tools for Xamarin has moved from Oracle's JDK to a **lightweight version of the OpenJDK that is intended solely for Android development**.  だそうです。

Comment: 同じく関係不明ですが、こんな記事があります。["java.exe" exited with code 2 Xamarin.Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44004161/9014308)

Comment: kunif 様 Multi-Dexを有効にしたところ、"AdjustJavacVersionArguments" タスクが予期せずに失敗しました。
System.NullReferenceException: オブジェクト参照がオブジェクト インスタンスに設定されていません。
   場所 Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AdjustJavacVersionArguments.Execute()
   場所 Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   場所 Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext(). プロジェクト: helloworld! と出てしまいました。

Comment: metropolis 様 JDKは 'C:\Java\jdk'、JREは'C:\Java\jre' にあります。コントロールパネルからJavaのアップデートの確認をしましたが、最新版とのことでした。 また、VSのバージョンは14.0.25420.1 でした。

Comment: (おそらく)Java11 から JRE は配布されなくなりました。これは、runtime が JDK に一本化されたためです。なので、`C:\Java\jdk` にインストールされた JDK と `C:\Java\jre` にインストールされている JRE のバージョンが異なっているはずです。

Comment: metropolis 様 JDKもJREもどちらも最新版(JDK:13.0.1 / JRE:Version8 update 231)をダウンロードしています。それとも、JDK8u231というものををダウンロードしたほうが良いのでしょうか。

Comment: Java 13 か Java 8 のどちらかに一本化した方が良いかと思います。ただ、先に紹介した Microsoft のアナウンスでは、Android SDK パッケージに改造版の OpenJDK が含まれていて、そちらを使う事を推奨しています。

Comment: metropolis 様 Java 8 で一本化したところ、少なくともビルドができない問題は解消いたしました。配置エラーが出たりとまだまだエラーは残っていますが、少なくともこの問題については完全に解決いたしました。様々な情報をご提供くださりありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

**JDK** (13.0.1) と **JRE** (1.8.0) が同時に別のフォルダ (`C:\Java\jdk` と `C:\Java\jre`) にインストールされた状態でしたが、Java 8 に一本化したところ、少なくともビルドができない問題は解決しました。

---

*この投稿は [@user37155 さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/61666/javac-exe%e3%81%af%e3%82%b3%e3%83%bc%e3%83%892%e3%82%92%e4%bc%b4%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e7%b5%82%e4%ba%86%e3%81%97%e3%81%be%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f-%e3%81%8c%e5%87%ba%e3%81%a6%e3%83%93%e3%83%ab%e3%83%89%e3%81%8c%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84#comment67285_61666) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*